# JavaScript: variable is undefined inside await

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have a code snippet below which outputs the description `meta` tag from StackOverflow's site. My problem is that I got an error saying `url` inside page.evaluate() is undefined while I explicitly defined the const `url` at the very beginning. I am not very familiar with the variable scope in JS, may I know why I got this error and what would be the fix for it?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";

function run () {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        try {
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage();
            await page.goto(url);
            
            let temp = await page.evaluate(() => {
                let metaTag = document.querySelector('head > [name="description"]');
                const output = url + ": " + metaTag.getAttribute('content');
                return output;
            })

            browser.close();
            return resolve(temp);
        } catch (error) {
            return reject(error)
        }
    })
}

run().then(console.log).catch(console.error);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't a problem with your understanding of variable scope in JS.

`page.evaluate` just doesn't behave normally because the function is evaluated in the context of the page instead of the context where it is defined.

If you want to pass data to it, do so as an argument:

```
let temp = await page.evaluate((url) => {
    // ...
}, url)
```